# VBA - Excel to powerpoint crashes for multiple ranges

Tags: excel, vba, macos, powerpoint

I'm trying to create PowerPoint presentations automatically using Excel(ver 16.31) VBA on MacBook. I'm using the following code:

```
Sub ExportToPowerPoint()

    'Declare PowerPoint variables
    Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim ExclRange As Range
    Dim RangeArray As Variant

    'Create a new instance of PowerPoint
    Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPTApp.Visible = True

    'Create a new Presentation
    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add

    'Create an Array that stores references to the ranges that we want to store
    RangeArray = Array(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:N18"), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:I17"), Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:J17"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:J17"))

    'Loop through this array, copy the range, create a new slide, and then paste the range to ther slide
    For x = LBound(RangeArray) To UBound(RangeArray)
    
            'Set a reference to the range we want to export
            Set ExclRange = RangeArray(x)
    
            'Copy the range
            ExclRange.Copy
            
            'Create the new slide in the Presentation - wait for a second
            Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(x + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
            
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
            
    
            'Paste the range in the slide
            PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
            
    Next x
           
End Sub
```

Seems like the code crashes at the last line PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste, when Powerpoint crashes and as a result Excel also hangs. If I comment out this line, 4 empty slides are created. Number of posts have mentioned to increase the wait time. However, even increasing wait time to 5 secs gives the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If Powerpoint or Excel crashes that means it is not an error in the VBA code but a bug in the application. So make sure to update to the latest version. Check if the same code has the same issue in other computers with the same Office version too. If it works on other computers you can try to re-install Office completely. If it fails on other computers file a support case with Microsoft as this is not a coding issue but a bug then.

Comment: What you can try is first add the slide and then copy/paste. So instead of copy>add>paste do add>copy>paste (just a try but probably the same effect.). But doing other things between copy and paste can always be tricky with Excel and make it fail.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Updated to the latest version of Excel and PowerPoint. Also tried add>copy>paste. However, it is still not working.

Comment: Well looks like a bug in Excel or Powerpoint then. File a support case at Microsoft.